# What causes the type mismatch in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub FillMissingNumbers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rrr As Range
    Dim maxNumber As Long
    Dim missingNumber As Long
    Dim category As String
    Dim cel As String
    Dim mismatchFound As Boolean
    
    ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual worksheet name
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ' Find the last used row in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Get the range of numbers and categories
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:B" & lastRow)
    
    ' Find the maximum number in column A
    maxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow))
    
    ' Check if there are missing numbers in each category
    For i = 1 To maxNumber
        missingNumber = 0
        For Each cell In rng
            If IsNumeric(cell.value) And cell.value = i Then
                category = cell.Offset(0, 1).value
                Exit For
            ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng.Columns(1), i) = 0 Then
                missingNumber = i
            End If
        Next cell
        If missingNumber > 0 Then Exit For
    Next i
    
    ' If there is a missing number, fill it based on its category
    If missingNumber > 0 Then
    cel = cell.Offset(0, 1).value
    MsgBox (cel)
        For Each cell In rng.Columns(1)
        'MsgBox (cell.Offset(0, 0).value)
        If (IsString(cell.Offset(0, 1).value) And (StrComp(CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).value), "A", vbTextCompare) = 0)) Then
        End If
            If IsEmpty(cell.value) And (IsString(cell.Offset(0, 1).value) And (StrComp(CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).value), "A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Or StrComp(CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).value), "B", vbTextCompare) = 0)) Then
                cell.value = missingNumber
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    Else
        ' If the list is complete, add 1 to the max number in column A
        For Each cell In rng.Columns(1)
            If IsNumeric(cell.value) And cell.value = maxNumber And (IsString(cell.Offset(0, 1).value) And (StrComp(CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).value), "A", vbTextCompare) = 0 Or StrComp(CStr(cell.Offset(0, 1).value), "B", vbTextCompare) = 0)) Then
                cell.value = maxNumber + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub

Function IsString(value As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsError(value) Then
        IsString = False
    ElseIf IsObject(value) Then
        IsString = False
    ElseIf VarType(value) = vbString Then
        IsString = True
    End If
End Function
```

I am trying to run this code to fill the missing number in two col A & B, but i stubern in error "Type Mismatch"

Comment: You have to use a variable in your `for each` loop - but you are using `cell` which isn't declared but a property --> `Dim c as range`  and then `For each c in rng.Columns(1)`

Comment: @Ike: `Cell` is a perfectly valid name for a variable and it is not a property (that's `Cells`). The problem is that `rng.Columns(1)` is a Range with all cells of column 1 of `rng`, not a single cell

Answer (score 2):

You missed to tell us which line throws the error. The problem I see is that your loop `For Each cell In rng.Columns(1)` is wrong: `rng.Columns(1)` will return the first column of Range `rng` - and unless your data only contains one row, this is still a range of multiple cells. All following commands (like `IsString(cell.Offset(0, 1).value)` will fail because they can only work on single values, not ranges.

To loop over all single cells, change your loop to

```
For Each cell In rng.Columns(1).Cells
```

An advice: Always use `Option Explicit` and declare all variables, this will save you a lot of hassle.